# Can't work out why jQuery UI Datepicker does not insert date into input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI Datepicker, which is initialising correctly on the input, but doesn't insert the selected value into the field.

The input is:

```
<input name="data[entry-date]" id="parkingEntryDate" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" class="date-input">
```

The JS is:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  dayNamesMin: [ "S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S" ],
  minDate: "d",
  maxDate: "+1y",
  prevText: "",
  nextText: "",
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
          }
});

$('#parkingEntryDate').datepicker();
```

The calendar shows as expected, I see the correct date in the alert onSelect, but the date does not get inserted into the input as the value; it stays blank and doesn't accept keyboard input, as expected.

Scripts are loaded in the right order using WordPress enqueue_script, and datepicker is initialised in last main.js.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook-pro.local:5757/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook-pro.local:5757/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
</head>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook-pro.local:5757/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook-pro.local:5757/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook-pro.local:5757/content/themes/mytheme/js/plugins.min.js?ver=20151215'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook-pro.local:5757/content/themes/mytheme/js/main.js?ver=20151215'></script>
```

No errors in inpector or console, and can't seem to think of what could be going on. Hoping someone more experience with JS or jQuery UI than I has experienced similar and/or can point me in a direction of where to look for an issue next.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `id` from the inputs and initialising the datepicker with the class worked. I'm 100% sure the `id` is unique and wasn't used or referenced anywhere else in CSS or JS. I have no idea why this worked - it doesn't make sense to me, but I'm over it.

If anyone knows why, I would be interested.

Hope this helps a future codesmith.

Comment: The reason this happens is because datepicker() assigns it's own id to the input element when it initialises.